# How to get the current loaded rows/items of a RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a list of items in my `RecyclerView` and I need to get the currently loaded items (i.e. not the recycled or off screen items) at a time.

This is may adapter

```
class MyAdapter(list: List<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    private var items: List<String> = list

    class MyViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val myText = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.my_text);
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val listItem: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(listItem)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.myText.text = items[position]
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = items.size

}
```

And RecyclerView:

```
recyclerView.apply { 
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
    hasFixedSize()
    adapter = MyAdapter(listOf("a", "b", "c"))  // List is bigger than that
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd a case that I needed to ensure how many RecyclerView items are currently loaded in order to control a performance issue; so that created this for someone else was looking for an answer.

You need to track the list of loaded & recycled items:

- The items are loaded in [`onBindViewHolder()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int)) callback
- The items are recycled in [`onViewRecycled()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onViewRecycled(VH)) callback

So, we can create a local list that tracks the current loaded item positions, add new positions in `onBindViewHolder()` and remove recycled ones in `onViewRecycled()`

In the below code the `currentLoadedPositions` tracks the loaded positions, and you can create a method that returns it:

```
class MyAdapter(list: List<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    private var items: List<String> = list

    // Tracking the currently loaded items in the RecyclerView
    private val currentLoadedPositions: ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()

    fun getLoadedPositions(): ArrayList<Int> {
        return currentLoadedPositions
    }


    class MyViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val myText = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.my_text)

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val listItem: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(listItem)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = items[position]
        holder.myText.text = item
        currentLoadedPositions.add(position)
        Log.d("LOG_TAG", "onViewRecycled: $currentLoadedPositions")
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = items.size

    override fun onViewRecycled(holder: MyViewHolder) {
        currentLoadedPositions.remove(Integer.valueOf(holder.adapterPosition));
        Log.d("LOG_TAG", "onViewRecycled: $currentLoadedPositions")
    }
}
```